# Use of binomial coefficient in order statistics

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Appreciate all your help with the following:

Let $U_{1}, ... U_{n}$ be n independent and uniformly distributed on (0,1) random variables. Let $U_{(1)} \geq U_{(2)} \geq ... \geq U_{(n)}$ be an ordering of the $U_{i}$'s in descending order. Find P($U_{(2)} \lt$ u).

My solution: 
P(($U_{(1)} \geq u) \cap (U_{(2)} < u)) = u^{n} + u^{n-1}(1-u)$

The correct solution is: $u^{n} + \binom{n}{1} u^{n-1}(1-u)$

What I do not understand is why would you need the $\binom{n}{1}$ part if the set of RV is already ordered and that you would have already known that which is the largest element already?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the point that addresses your question is that even though you have ordered your random variables as $U_{(1)}\geq U_{(2)} \geq \cdots \geq U_{(n)}$, you *do not know* which random variable among the $U_i$ that is largest. The order statistics are still random variables: You only declare that $U_{(1)} = \max\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n\}$ and so on, but you do not know which of the $U_i$ will be $U_{(1)}$, which will be $U_{(2)}$ etc.

I would do the calculation somewhat along the following lines:

$$P(U_{(2)} < u) = P((U_{(1)} < u)\cup(U_{(1)}>u,U_{(2)}<u))$$
$$=P(U_{(1)} < u) + P(U_{(1)}>u,U_{(2)}<u)$$
$$=u^n + P(U_{(1)}>u,U_{(2)}<u)$$
$$=u^n + P(U_i>u\text{ for some }i, U_j<u\text{ for all }j\neq i).$$

Here I have used that $P(U_{(1)} < u) = P(\max\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n\} <u) = P(U_i<u\text{ for all }i)=u^n$.

Also, the probability $P(U_i>u\text{ for some }i, U_j<u\text{ for all }j\neq i)$ can be calculated by noting that you need to choose *one* $U_i$ that is larger that $u$. You can do this in $\binom{n}{1}$ ways. Then this chosen $U_i$ is larger than $u$ with probability $1-u$, and the rest $n-1$ of the $U_i$ is smaller than $u$ with probability $u^{n-1}$ (by independence).

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hello, thank you - this is very clear. Your first paragraph summed it up and I was able to follow through with your workings as well, that's great! Basically the essence is that even after assignment of the indexes to the elements, the ordered elements still remain as random variables. I suppose my mistake above was that I was thinking in terms of an observed sample, which should not be the case!

Comment: @SanjouOdawali you're welcome.